# Language changed to Chinese, how do I change it back?

Tags: language-support

I am using latest ubuntu. My language changed to chinese somehow.
Everything comes in chinese and I couldn't get it back to english.
Tried changing in language support, but english is written in chinese which I
don't understand :(

Is there a way to change back to english using terminal and not gui way?

Comment: English in Chinese is 英語 (Traditional) and 英语 (Simplefied), hopefully that way you can recognize it in the GUI.

Comment: Oddly, for me it seems to be a low battery issue. When my battery gets dangerously low my phone language switches to chinese. What a hoot: go to settings, language and input, samsung keyboard and select english and de-select everything else. Problem solved... at least on the note 3.

Answer (score 5):

Exactly the same thing happened to me just now.

English in Chinese is 英語 (Traditional) and 英语 (Simplefied) (thanks - and copied from comment from @titaniumtux)

I was able to change it back using the keyboard layout options in Settings.

Answer (score 5):

The `~/.pam_environment` file was the source of my problem. In `/etc/default/locale` and  `~/.pam_environment`

I edited the second file here to have:

```
LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8:en
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

(for US users). You will probably see other entries in
.pam_environment that are correct, so you can cut and paste
these into the above two variables. Note the ending ":en"
for the LANGUAGE variable which appears to be unique for
that variable.

From sacadough on the thread:

- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1969183

Comment: This is a much better answer than @adamoxford because it allows you  to fix the problem without having to try to figure out Chome's settings page that, because of the bug, is in Chinese! Thanks a ton!!!

Answer (score 0):

**Solved the Language issue by a logical way.**

Today my Ubuntu 10.04 shows menus and sub-menus in **Chinese (中文)** Language. Even *Terminal* too.

1. I used *trial and error* method. Finally Solved my issue.
2. I took 
   *Keyboard Layout settings*  from Panel.
3. A pop-up window appeared. But I couldn’t read there anything in *Languages* menu. Because Chinese
   Language was there.
4. I took *English to Chinese* in Google search. Typed
   English (United States) In the box for Enlish and google converted
   it to 英语（美国)
5. Searched the letters in my *Languages* menu and i found
   it. (There was a heading, '**Change will be applied next time you
   login**'- "Yes, remember it")
6. Again I took the next menu in *Keyboard
   layout* named *Formats*, changed the format to  英语（美国); this means
   English (United states) - "Thanks, google". (If we cannot see the 英语（美国) English (United states), You click on the "+" button in the bottom and select which you want from there
7. Just closed the pop-up
   window and System Rebooted. All menus and Sub-menus Smiled with English(US) language. Solved my issue!!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you have to do:

Just fix the locales with this process:

First run `locale` to list what locales currently defined for the current user account:

```bash
$ locale
LANG=C
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE=fi_FI.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_COLLATE=fi_FI.UTF-8
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_MESSAGES=fi_FI.UTF-8
LC_PAPER="C"
LC_NAME="C"
LC_ADDRESS="C"
LC_TELEPHONE="C"
LC_MEASUREMENT="C"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="C"
LC_ALL=
```

Then generate the missing locale and reconfigure locales to take notice:

```bash
$ sudo locale-gen "en_US.UTF-8"
Generating locales...
  en_US.UTF-8... done
Generation complete.

$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
Generating locales...
  en_US.UTF-8... up-to-date
Generation complete.
```

Now, that will fix both your locales, but also it will default your language to english to fix the problem.

For more view this: [How do I fix my locale issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162391/how-do-i-fix-my-locale-issue)