# How do I fix my locale issue?

Tags: command-line, server, locale

I am getting this message every time I do something like starting or stopping a service.

```
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.   
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:   
        LANGUAGE = "en_US:en",   
        LC_ALL = (unset),   
        LC_MESSAGES = "en_US.UTF-8",   
        LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"   
    are supported and installed on your system.   
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").   
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory   
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory   
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory   
(Reading database ... 21173 files and directories currently installed.)  
Removing bind9 ...  
 * Stopping domain name service... bind9                                        [ OK ]
Processing triggers for man-db ...   
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory   
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory   
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
```

How do I fix this error ?

Comment: Related: [How to set locale?](http://askubuntu.com/q/17001/62483)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Locale variables have no effect in remote shell (perl: warning: Setting locale failed.)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/144235/locale-variables-have-no-effect-in-remote-shell-perl-warning-setting-locale-f)

Comment: Easy and permanent fix for all users: https://askubuntu.com/questions/881742/locale-cannot-set-lc-ctype-to-default-locale-no-such-file-or-directory-locale/893586#893586

Comment: You need to say: Your machine? Or you only have a user-login and can't change system-settings? (Yeah I know this is a really old question. And the upvotes of wrong answers is appalling)

Answer (score 589, accepted):

First run `locale` to list what locales currently defined for the current user account:

```bsh
$ locale
LANG=C
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE=fi_FI.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_COLLATE=fi_FI.UTF-8
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_MESSAGES=fi_FI.UTF-8
LC_PAPER="C"
LC_NAME="C"
LC_ADDRESS="C"
LC_TELEPHONE="C"
LC_MEASUREMENT="C"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="C"
LC_ALL=
```

Then generate the missing locale and reconfigure locales to take notice:

```bsh
$ sudo locale-gen "en_US.UTF-8"
Generating locales...
  en_US.UTF-8... done
Generation complete.

$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
Generating locales...
  en_US.UTF-8... up-to-date
Generation complete.
```

Now you will not see any errors anymore!

Comment: did not work for me

Comment: This has worked for me on a number of systems. Is there a way to avoid this issue on newly installed systems?

Comment: @UmairAyub may be you have more than one unknow locale, try this: **for y in $(locale | cut -d '=' -f 2| sort |uniq );do locale-gen $y; done**
It will generate a locale for each definition you have

Comment: The locale in the `locale-gen` command should be in double quotes for this to work properly: `$ sudo locale-gen "en_US.UTF-8"`

Comment: this didn't work for me in ubuntu 14.04, I'm still getting console errors.

Comment: so finally I had to add export LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8" manually in my .bachrc file. and this fixed the error prompts. But... why is that this variable wasn't configured by gen-locale ? isn't this supposed to be managed by this command ?

Comment: Logout and Login may help

Comment: @S.M.Mousavi Tried rebooting as well, only manually exporting the variables seems to fix the issue

Comment: Remember open a new terminal to test it

Comment: @Umair There is a high risk of human error in this problem. Your system is configured to `en_GB` by default, but you set it up to `en_US`. You have to manually comment `en_GB` and uncomment `en_US` in `/etc/locale.gen`. See my answer http://askubuntu.com/a/790373/25388 in the hardware Raspberry Pi 3b and the system Raspbian Jessie.

Comment: Thanks. I was not able to update my softwares for so long and sometimes the operating system used to crash because of stopping the process and restarting the system

Comment: In fact it only worked when executing "sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales" -> select "en_US.UTF-8" from the long list (use space to select) -> Enter -> select again en_US.UTF-8 as default -> Enter.

Comment: my two cents, 

you might need to install `locales` first, especially if you got an error from just trying `locale -a`

On Ubuntu, simply install locales by this command
`sudo apt-get install locales`

Comment: Worked perfectly in Windows Subsystem for Linux under Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS. Not sure how locales got broken but this fixed it.

Comment: Works great!. It really helps

Comment: I had to type `159` and than `3` after running `sudo locale-gen "en_US.UTF-8"`

Comment: This worked for me even though `/etc/default/locale` and the output of `locale` don't get changed.

Comment: `locale-gen` does not take any arguments, it just generates all locales that have previously been selected via `dpkg-reconfigure locales`, so it's useless here.

Answer (score 420):

Nothing suggested above worked in my case (Ubuntu Server 12.04LTS). What finally helped 
was putting to the file `/etc/environment`:

```
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

For some reason it was missing. The outputs for locale and other commands appeared like the variables were properly defined. In other words don't take for granted all the basic stuff is declared where it should be declared.

Comment: Yes, none other worked except this one, perhaps due to updated version. But I rather prefer to put this in `/etc/default/locale`.

Comment: Updated `/etc/default/locale` and no more warnings. Thanks

Comment: Yep, the others didn't work for me. This one did.
Here is the one-liner I used for unattended updating of this.

    `sudo sh -c "echo 'LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8\nLANG=en_US.UTF-8' >> /etc/environment"`

Comment: @user163207 your solution is incorrect because it appends (instead of overwriting), it's not the recommended file, and `echo` needs to be run with the interpretation of backslash escapes enabled. This is the same as yours but with the aforementioned fixed: `sh -c "echo -e 'LANG=en_US.UTF-8\nLC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8' > /etc/default/locale"`

Comment: I am facing the same issue in my Ubuntu Cloud Image

Comment: I used this method but I quoted the locale value, like ``LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"`` then I still got the error. Removing that quote fix the problem.

Comment: You need to log-out and log back in for these changes to have any effect.

Comment: (Old question, I know, but) LC_ALL should NOT be touched, it's an override (for all (the other) locale settings), local and remote. It means that you're, basically, forcing it (which I don't think is a viable solution :))

Comment: DON'T FORGET TO LOGPUT AND RE-LOGIN!

Comment: This is what worked for me on a fresh Raspbian install.  `/etc/default/locale` only had the LANG line without an LC_ALL line.

Comment: @Nostromov If I leave out the LC_ALL line, I'll continue getting errors. This is the only viable and reliable solution that works for me. Anything I should watch out for as a result of setting LC_ALL?

Comment: it is need exit of session and relogin

Comment: Just want to say that this works.

Comment: @glarrain To apply a partial fix on this base is dangerous: Just making it to overwrite deletes other parts of `/etc/environment`. It will work, without complaining - but may break something to be noticed much later.

Comment: @prasanthchandra : Where are the errors appearing?  Which file have you put this in (see glarain's answer)? And fundamentally : What is output of (1) locale and (2) locale -a?

Comment: Basically @nostromov is correct.  LC_ALL should **not** be set. If things get to "working" by setting it it's a kludge – something somewhere else is broken. And remains so

Answer (score 174):

They should disappear after issuing:

```
sudo locale-gen en_US en_US.UTF-8
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

---

`dpkg-reconfigure` reconfigures packages after they have already been
       installed. Pass it the names of a package or packages to reconfigure.
       It will ask configuration questions, much like when the package was
       first installed.

Comment: I am glad my troubles a year ago helped you get this fixed ;)

Comment: Shouldn't this locale be generated by default? I mean `en`, `en_AU`, `en_CA`, `en_GB` are present by default but not `en_US`?

Comment: @Rinzwind Thanks a lot for your effort! I do apologize; I should have worded my question better. What I meant to ask is: Why is it necessary to reconfigure the locales package after generating new locales? Seems to me like the locales work even without `dpkg-reconfigure`.

Comment: Using Ubuntu 14.04, in a Docker container, so nothing was being set. Django's `makemessage` needs this. This worked perfectly! thanks.

Comment: I believe the `sudo` is missing. Perhaps it should be: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales`. This worked for me after a fresh install of Ubunty 14.10 Desktop 64-bit.

Comment: Logout and Login after above solution may help.

Comment: somehow `sudo locale-gen en_US` is required on top `en_US.UTF8`. hopefully it will solve the issue for good (after multiple Ubuntu versions)

Comment: It just is the perfect solution.

Comment: Fow AWS EC2 , this will work.

Comment: I realize that raspbian is out of scope here, but I thought I'd mention that I had to logout and login before `LC_ALL` was properly set.

Comment: Thank you! This, but not the other answers, solved my problem with Ubuntu 19.10 on AWS EC2.

Answer (score 145):

Just add the following to your `.bashrc` file (assuming you're using bash)

```
export LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
```

Comment: This sweet fix worked for me on my Amazon-EC2 image (Was running their default RHEL AMI) Thanks so much! :)

Comment: This one worked for me with my digitalocean's Ubuntu 12.04 image.

Comment: this fixed my problem. I have to ask a question: how come the LC_ALL was not set by the locale-gen command as other answers said above this one ?

Comment: Weird, all solution above didn't work for me but this one did! After exporting `LC_ALL` I could finally use `sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales`.

Comment: finally after trying a lot of tricks , this is the working one for me on kubuntu 14.04.3 lts . thanks!

Comment: @sobi3ch And thereafter you likely don't need LC_ALL. (You should find LANG properly set after the reconfigure)  ie as *temporary* hack setting it is fine. Stable long-term not. (Yeah thus is **old**. Sayin' because it's currently reinforcing a bad practice)

Comment: I was using `zsh` (oh-my-zsh) but this was what finally pointed me in the right direction. `~/.zshrc` contains the lines: ```# You may need to manually set your language environment
# export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
``` Uncommenting the `export LANG` line fixed it for me with `xfce4-terminal` on Ubuntu 18.04 (in a stripped-down VM with XFCE desktop.)

Comment: old comment but just saved me on Ubuntu 20.04 lts :)

Answer (score 109):

This is a common problem if you are connecting remotely, so the solution is to not forward your locale. Edit `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` and comment out `SendEnv LANG LC_*` line.

Comment: I was trying other answers, but forgot I was connecting remotely until I saw your answer. Different locales on the ssh server and client was causing the problem.

Comment: On OSX (connecting to ubuntu) it's at `/etc/ssh_config`

Comment: One-liner to do this: `sed -e '/SendEnv/ s/^#*/#/' -i /etc/ssh/ssh_config` (useful for server provisioning)

Comment: I couldn't set LC_ALL on the locale machine but it fixed my problem with  the remote server, thanks.

Comment: Probably worth noting that you have to edit the file on the local machine not the remote.

Comment: Perfect. I tried all other answers, none of them worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: On macOS High Sierra, It's still `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`.

Comment: And this works for AWS EC2 instances.

Answer (score 95):

There is a command for that:

```
sudo update-locale LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

It updates `/etc/default/locale` with provided values.

To apply the changes, you can

```
source /etc/default/locale
```

Comment: This is legit! Don't forget to sign out / reload your shell, or else you won't see the changes. Don't forget to check out the approved answer for generating and reconfiguring locales.

Comment: Running `locale` still doesn't show any utf values.

Comment: @Cerin: Myybe, a call to `locale-gen` is missing. Before, one has to do `apt-get install locales`.

Comment: This won't change LANG for the root shell on Ubuntu 16.04, as it is overruled in /root/.profile.

Comment: `*** update-locale: Error: invalid locale settings:  LANG=en_US.UTF-8 LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8`

Comment: @alper You first need to `locale-gen "en_US.UTF-8"` and then and only then check it on `sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales`

Comment: This `update-locale` is what solved the problem after about 2 hours tring to install a package that compain, so "Really: thanks"

Answer (score 37):

What worked for me on 12.10 was this:

```
apt-get install language-pack-en-base
```

This was after `dpkg-reconfigure locales` produced no results.

Comment: This is the best answer.  It's not that my locales were setup incorrectly, but they didn't actually exist.  I think this is similar to the OP's problem as well ("No such file or directory" is pretty clear if your locale *is* set right!).

Comment: I was getting the OPs issue ever time i was using apt-get on Ubuntu 12.04 This solved it perfectly without having to edit any files.

Comment: "language-pack-en-base is already the newest version."

Comment: Logout and Login may help

Comment: Worked for me in an ubuntu `chroot` under debian. Thanks :)

Comment: I'd extend the solution: you can generate a command to install all the languages currently mentioned in your locale (whatever mix it may be). Here it is: `locale|tr -d '"'|cut -d= -f2|cut -d_ -f1|sort|uniq|while read lang; do [[ $lang ]] && echo apt install language-pack-$lang-base; done` (I won't state that it's the shortest possible, but it works).

Comment: This also works on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Comment: This doesn't work on Debian, while `apt-get install locales-all` worked fine

Answer (score 22):

Don't forget exit your SSH session (or your X11) by exiting and logging back in again. All of these suggestions didn't work for me unless I logged back in....

Comment: This comment should get more upvotes or atleast the fact needs to be highlighted in every answer.

Answer (score 14):

I was stuck in a weird state where my local machine is set to `es` and so the remote machine (via `vagrant`) had been provisioned in an un-handled state. Therefore, I had to use the manual `export=` only to facilitate a successful `dpkg-reconfigure`. Then the system is fine.

```
export LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

Comment: Best! Due to `dpkg-recofigure` displays mojibake.

Comment: This is the only one works.

Answer (score 13):

For Ubuntu 12.10 none of the above worked except for ratzs' solution. I recommend adding this to your /etc/bash.bashrc file:

```
export LC_ALL="en_ZA.UTF-8"
export LC_CTYPE="en_ZA.UTF-8"
```

Comment: Of all the solutions above. This is the only that worked for me.

Answer (score 11):

I wrote a [bash script](http://jee-appy.blogspot.com/2016/02/set-locale-on-ubuntu-permanent-solution.html) to fix above issue.The above answers are useful but setting the locale variables by simply exporting the values in shell variable will work only for a session. I permanently solved this issue by exporting the locale variables in .bash_profile file. You can also use `/etc/profile` file instead of `.bash_profile`.

```
echo "export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8">>~/.bash_profile
```

Don't forget to `source` the `.bash_profile` and follow the [script](http://jee-appy.blogspot.com/2016/02/set-locale-on-ubuntu-permanent-solution.html) in easy setup.

Answer (score 9):

You can try:

```
export LANGUAGE=ru_RU.UTF-8
export LC_CTYPE=ru_RU.UTF-8
export LC_NUMERIC=ru_RU.UTF-8
export LC_TIME=ru_RU.UTF-8
export LC_COLLATE=ru_RU.UTF-8
export LC_MONETARY=ru_RU.UTF-8
export LC_MESSAGES=ru_RU.UTF-8
export LC_PAPER=ru_RU.UTF-8
export LC_NAME=ru_RU.UTF-8
export LC_ADDRESS=ru_RU.UTF-8
export LC_TELEPHONE=ru_RU.UTF-8
export LC_MEASUREMENT=ru_RU.UTF-8
export LC_IDENTIFICATION=ru_RU.UTF-8
export LC_ALL=ru_RU.UTF-8
```

where `ru_RU` is your country code.

Answer (score 8):

Current accepted answer is not sufficient in the troubleshoot strategy because you can have an human error. 
You setup your system to `en_US` but you have `en_GB` enabled in`/etc/locale.gen` like I had in the thread [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/287716/16920) for Raspberry Pi 3b. 
You should have **all** your used locales enabled in `/etc/locale.gen`.

I had `en_GB.UTF-8 UTF-8` only enabled in `/etc/locale.gen`. I should have there only enabled `en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8` because of other commands run for it. So I commented GB and uncommented US, and everything work now

```
masi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo vim /etc/locale.gen

masi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo locale-gen 
Generating locales (this might take a while)...
  en_US.UTF-8... done
Generation complete.

masi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo a2enmod rewrite && a2enmod headers && a2enmod ssl
Module rewrite already enabled
Module headers already enabled
Considering dependency setenvif for ssl:
Module setenvif already enabled
Considering dependency mime for ssl:
Module mime already enabled
Considering dependency socache_shmcb for ssl:
Module socache_shmcb already enabled
Module ssl already enabled
```

Now, I do not get those locale mistakes with any commands.

System: Raspbian Jessie
Hardware: Raspberry Pi 3b

Answer (score 7):

As said [here in the Debian Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/Locale#Manually), you can edit `/etc/locale.gen` and add all locales (or uncomment them, I had a list of all locales but all except the one I used as comments) you wish to have support for on your system. Then, execute

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

to update the locales on your system. Now, all of the locales you added/uncommented in `/etc/locale.gen` are available on your system without any warnings.

Answer (score 5):

If you use KDE environment, check the `setlocale.sh` file in `~/.kde/env/`:

```
$ cat ~/.kde/env/setlocale.sh 
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LANGUAGE=en_US:ru:en
```

Comment: this saved my ass....  thank you! Unbelievable how many places this locale crap is being set in... and how in the world does KDE manage to screw things up by mixing my two different locales (is_IS for location, money, etc and en_EN for language into a non-existent is_EN locale)! Grmpfh.

Comment: I have been struggling with this for weeks! No other answer helped me. I couldn't even assume that KDE messes with the locale in its own way. I didn't know about the `setlocale.sh` file and not a single tutorial mentions it.

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me when I had the same problem (based on the solution [provided by dman](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162391/how-do-i-fix-my-locale-issue/516568#comment570447_229512)):

```
sudo sh -c "echo -e 'LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8\nLANG=en_US.UTF-8' >> /etc/environment"
```

Comment: I wasn't quite sure how to add the url to the comment. @EliahKagan

Comment: No problem--the date/timestamp next to a comment is what links to it directly. ...So, I've noticed [glarrain's comment](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162391/how-do-i-fix-my-locale-issue/516568?noredirect=1#comment584032_229512) (calling for `>` instead of `>>`) seems like a reply to dman's. I don't actually know which way is right or best, but if you have any insight into this you could expand this answer with more information. (You don't have to though.)

Answer (score 3):

1. You may need to run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure` also for the application you have installed while "locale" settings have been invalid / not matching.

   While system locale was incorrectly setup I installed `vim`.  Later when system locale was fixed I saw a situation that `vim` was showing utf-8 characters incorrectly as strange symbols while `nano` and `less` were showing them correctly. Running

   ```
   sudo dpkg-reconfigure vim
   ```

   appeared to fix the issue after the system settings were fixed.
2. I also noticed the same thing as already mentioned: You may need to disconnect/reconnect SSH to make changes visible.

Answer (score 3):

Adding the following text to `~/.profile` works for me:

```
export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64-bit server on Linode.

Answer (score 1):

### Source of the problem

I experienced this, logging in from one machine to another via `ssh`. The remote machine didn’t have the locale files, that I had on my local machine. You can either disable the forwarding of the locale from your local machine to the remote machine (in the file `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` remove the line `AcceptEnv LANG LC_CTYPE …`) or install the locale (changing it is not necessary in this case).

### Installing

On Fedora, RHEL, Redhat, CentOS I used

```
sudo dnf install langpacks-de
```

for the german (de) language packs. Logged out and in and it worked.

Search for other langpacks with

```
dnf search langpacks-
```

### Changing/Activating

To list available locales I used

```
localectl list-locales
```

And to set a new one

```
sudo localectl set-locale de_DE.utf8
```

Comment: `dnf` are not Ubuntu or *flavor* commands, how is this helpful on this site?  https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Comment: This problem is not specifically an Ubuntu problem. I gave general instructions in the first paragraph. And then an example of how to do it on a specific distribution, where I had the problem. It is basic knowledge how to translate that to another distributions package management system.

Comment: If you wanted to post this answer, I feel the question should have been re-asked on SE *Unix & Linux* and the answer used there, thus being on-topic.

Comment: My answer is absolutely on topic. None of the answers tells what the real problem is, the source of the problem. Package installation is trivial, or should be asked in a different question. It is quite similar on all distributions, also on Debian or Ubuntu. And the rest of the solution works fine on every modern linux distribution. **And** I mentioned explicitly my distributions. Instead of complaining you could **add** the Debian/Ubuntu commands. That would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

remove locales using localepurge you don't need and reboot

```
apt install localepurge
```