# dkms errors when updating / upgrading Ubuntu

Tags: upgrade, dkms

My system stopped an upgrading-process. It only boots into an old Kernel (Linux 5.19.0-40-generic). I have Ubuntu 23.04. When I try `sudo apt-upgrade` I get errors:

---

```
$ sudo apt upgrade
[sudo] password for pepp: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up linux-image-6.2.0-20-generic (6.2.0-20.20) ...
Setting up linux-headers-6.2.0-20-generic (6.2.0-20.20) ...
/etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 6.2.0-20-generic
Sign command: /usr/bin/kmodsign
Signing key: /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.priv
Public certificate (MOK): /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.der

Building module:
Cleaning build area...
'make' KVER=6.2.0-20-generic src=/usr/src/rtl88x2bu-5.8.7.1................................................(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for rtl88x2bu: 5.8.7.1 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.2.0-20-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtl88x2bu/5.8.7.1/build/make.log for more information.
Error! One or more modules failed to install during autoinstall.
Refer to previous errors for more information.
   ...fail!
run-parts: /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms exited with return code 11
dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-6.2.0-20-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-headers-6.2.0-20-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-headers-
generic:
 linux-headers-generic depends on linux-headers-6.2.0-20-generic; however:
  Package linux-headers-6.2.0-20-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic:
 linux-generic depends on linux-headers-generic (= 6.2.0.20.20); however:
  Package linux-headers-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Processing triggers for linux-image-6.2.0-20-generic (6.2.0-20.20
) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 6.2.0-20-generic
Sign command: /usr/bin/kmodsign
Signing key: /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.priv
Public certificate (MOK): /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.der

Building module:
Cleaning build area...
'make' KVER=6.2.0-20-generic src=/usr/src/rtl88x2bu-5.8.7.1.............................................(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for rtl88x2bu: 5.8.7.1 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.2.0-20-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtl88x2bu/5.8.7.1/build/make.log for more information.
Error! One or more modules failed to install during autoinstall.
Refer to previous errors for more information.
   ...fail!
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms exited with return code 11
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-6.2.0-20-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-6.2.0-20-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-headers-6.2.0-20-generic
 linux-headers-generic
 linux-generic
 linux-image-6.2.0-20-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Danke for your help everyone! I tried "sudo dkms remove -m rtl88x2bu -v 5.8.7.1 -k --all And sudo apt -f install". Unfortunately it returned errors:

---

```
pepp@pepp-E3216-MD61800:~$ sudo dkms remove -m rtl88x2bu -v 5.8.7.1 -k --all

[sudo] password for pepp:  Module rtl88x2bu 5.8.7.1 is not installed for kernel --all (x86_64). Skipping... Module rtl88x2bu 5.8.7.1 is not built for kernel --all (x86_64). Skipping... pepp@pepp-E3216-MD61800:~$ sudo apt -f install Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree... Done Reading state information... Done 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 25 not upgraded. 4 not fully installed or removed. After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used. Setting up linux-image-6.2.0-20-generic (6.2.0-20.20) ... Setting up linux-headers-6.2.0-20-generic (6.2.0-20.20) ... /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms:  * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 6.2.0-20-generic Sign command: /usr/bin/kmodsign Signing key: /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.priv Public certificate (MOK): /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.der

Building module: Cleaning build area... 'make' KVER=6.2.0-20-generic src=/usr/src/rtl88x2bu-5.8.7.1...............................................(bad exit status: 2) ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for rtl88x2bu:
5.8.7.1 not found Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.2.0-20-generic (x86_64) Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtl88x2bu/5.8.7.1/build/make.log for more information. Error! One or more modules failed to install during autoinstall. Refer to previous errors for more information.    ...fail! run-parts: /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms exited with return code 11 dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-6.2.0-20-generic (--configure): installed linux-headers-6.2.0-20-generic package post-installation script subpr ocess returned error exit status 1 dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-headers-generic:  linux-headers-generic depends on linux-headers-6.2.0-20-generic; however:   Package linux-headers-6.2.0-20-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-generic (--configure):  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic:  linux-generic depends on linux-headers-generic (= 6.2.0.20.20); however:   Package linux-headers-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-generic (--configure):  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup erro r from a previous failure.
                          No apport report written because the error message ind icates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                    Processing triggers for linu x-image-6.2.0-20-generic (6.2.0-20.20) ... /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms:  * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 6.2.0-20-generic Sign command: /usr/bin/kmodsign Signing key: /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.priv Public certificate (MOK): /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.der

Building module: Cleaning build area... 'make' KVER=6.2.0-20-generic src=/usr/src/rtl88x2bu-5.8.7.1..................... .............................(bad exit status: 2) ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for rtl88x2bu: 5.8.7.1 not found Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.2.0-20-generic (x86_64) Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtl88x2bu/5.8.7.1/build/make.log for more information. Error! One or more modules failed to install during autoinstall. Refer to previous errors for more information.    ...fail! run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms exited with return code 11 dpkg: error processing package linux-image-6.2.0-20-generic (--configure):  installed linux-image-6.2.0-20-generic package post-installation script subproc ess returned error exit status 1 No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encoun tered while processing:  linux-headers-6.2.0-20-generic  linux-headers-generic  linux-generic  linux-image-6.2.0-20-generic E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

When i enter "dpkg - l | grep dkms" i get:

```
$ dpkg - l | grep dkms
dpkg: error: need an action option

Type dpkg --help for help about installing and deinstalling packages [*];
Use 'apt' or 'aptitude' for user-friendly package management;
Type dpkg -Dhelp for a list of dpkg debug flag values;
Type dpkg --force-help for a list of forcing options;
Type dpkg-deb --help for help about manipulating *.deb files;

Options marked [*] produce a lot of output - pipe it through 'less' or 'more' !
```

i tried "$ dpkg - l | grep dkms:

```
dpkg: error: need an action option

Type dpkg --help for help about installing and deinstalling packages [*]; Use 'apt' or 'aptitude' for user-friendly package management; Type dpkg -Dhelp for a list of dpkg debug flag values; Type dpkg
--force-help for a list of forcing options; Type dpkg-deb --help for help about manipulating *.deb files;

Options marked [*] produce a lot of output - pipe it through 'less' or 'more' !
```

Now i tried "dpkg -l | grep dkms" an received:

```
>  ii  dkms                                             3.0.10-7        
> all          Dynamic Kernel Module System (DKMS)
```

Errors again :-(

---

```
sudo apt upgrade
```

[sudo] password for pepp:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
gnome-video-effects linux-generic linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic
ubuntu-drivers-common
The following packages will be upgraded:
cups-browsed linux-libc-dev
2 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 125 kB/1.661 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar-updates/main amd64 cups-browsed amd64 2.0~rc1-0ubuntu1.1 [125 kB]
Fetched 125 kB in 0s (264 kB/s)
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'linux-headers-5.15.0-46' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'linux-headers-5.15.0-46-generic' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
(Reading database ... 356329 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../cups-browsed_2.0~rc1-0ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking cups-browsed (2.0~rc1-0ubuntu1.1) over (2.0~rc1-0ubuntu1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../linux-libc-dev_6.2.0-24.24_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-libc-dev:amd64 (6.2.0-24.24) over (6.2.0-23.23) ...
Setting up cups-browsed (2.0~rc1-0ubuntu1.1) ...
Setting up linux-headers-6.2.0-23-generic (6.2.0-23.23) ...
/etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms:

- dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 6.2.0-23-generic
  Sign command: /usr/bin/kmodsign
  Signing key: /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.priv
  Public certificate (MOK): /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.der

Building module:
Cleaning build area...
'make' KVER=6.2.0-23-generic src=/usr/src/rtl88x2bu-5.8.7.1..................................................(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for rtl88x2bu: 5.8.7.1 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.2.0-23-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtl88x2bu/5.8.7.1/build/make.log for more information.
dkms autoinstall on 6.2.0-23-generic/x86_64 failed for rtl88x2bu(10)
Error! One or more modules failed to install during autoinstall.
Refer to previous errors for more information.
...fail!
run-parts: /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms exited with return code 11
dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-6.2.0-23-generic (--configure):
installed linux-headers-6.2.0-23-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Setting up linux-libc-dev:amd64 (6.2.0-24.24) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-headers-generic:
linux-headers-generic depends on linux-headers-6.2.0-23-generic; however:
Package linux-headers-6.2.0-23-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-generic (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up linux-image-6.2.0-23-generic (6.2.0-23.23) ...
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic:
linux-generic depends on linux-headers-generic (= 6.2.0.23.23); however:
Package linux-headers-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-generic (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
Processing triggers for man-db (2.11.2-1) ...
Processing triggers for linux-image-6.2.0-23-generic (6.2.0-23.23) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms:

- dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 6.2.0-23-generic
  Sign command: /usr/bin/kmodsign
  Signing key: /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.priv
  Public certificate (MOK): /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.der

Building module:
Cleaning build area...
'make' KVER=6.2.0-23-generic src=/usr/src/rtl88x2bu-5.8.7.1................................................(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for rtl88x2bu: 5.8.7.1 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.2.0-23-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtl88x2bu/5.8.7.1/build/make.log for more information.
dkms autoinstall on 6.2.0-23-generic/x86_64 failed for rtl88x2bu(10)
Error! One or more modules failed to install during autoinstall.
Refer to previous errors for more information.
...fail!
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms exited with return code 11
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-6.2.0-23-generic (--configure):
installed linux-image-6.2.0-23-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
Errors were encountered while processing:
linux-headers-6.2.0-23-generic
linux-headers-generic
linux-generic
linux-image-6.2.0-23-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: `dkms status` please.

Comment: dkms status
rtl88x2bu/5.8.7.1, 5.13.0-39-generic, x86_64: built

Comment: Oh verpennt. `sudo dkms remove -m rtl88x2bu -v 5.8.7.1 -k --all` And `sudo apt -f install`

Comment: Danke! Unfortunately it gave me errors:

Comment: Oh you have after cleaning the module from dkms tree remove the disturbing package `dpkg - l | grep dkms` please. I get old.

Comment: Danke für deine Hilfe, nobody!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Package linux-image-generic is not configured yet](https://askubuntu.com/questions/429731/package-linux-image-generic-is-not-configured-yet) and [Package linux-image-generic is not configured yet](https://askubuntu.com/q/429731/)

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo dkms remove -m rtl88x2bu -v 5.8.7.1 -k --all
```

Reomves the desturbing module again.

```
mkdir -p $HOME/apt-download/partial/
```

Then we download package dkms so your have it on your system.

```
sudo apt-get -d -o dir::cache::archives="$HOME/apt-download/" install --reinstall dkms
```

Now package dkms is in $HOME/apt-download/ so you can install with apt or dpkg for security reason; because we have to get rid of it first.

```
sudo dpkg -P dkms
```

Check with

```
df -h;df -i
```

if enough space and inodes free especially if you have an own boot filesystem.

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt -f install
```

Comment: Thank you so much, nobody! It finally worked. I had to reinstall dkms on the way, everything else worked smoothly. :-)))

Comment: @Peter saying thank you here is to accept the answer that works :D.