# dkms package not found and apt fails every time

Tags: apt, kernel, dpkg, dkms

After doing a normal `apt update && apt upgrade` I get a kernel panic on reboot.
I fixed it entering a shell from the old kernel recovery mode and then issuing:

```
mount -o remount,rw /
mkinitramfs -o /boot/initrd.img-6.5.0-14-generic 6.5.0-14-generic
update-grub
```

In this way I was able to boot again my Ubuntu 23.10.
But now every time `apt` is invoked it fails with the following messages (I apologize, some of the words are in Italian):

```
Configurazione di linux-headers-6.5.0-14-generic (6.5.0-14.14)...
/etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 6.5.0-14-generic
Sign command: /usr/bin/kmodsign
Signing key: /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.priv
Public certificate (MOK): /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.der

Building module:
Cleaning build area...
make -j8 KERNELRELEASE=6.5.0-14-generic default KERNELVERSION=6.5.0-14-generic..
.(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for ch340: 1.0.0 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.5.0-14-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/ch340/1.0.0/build/make.log for more information.
dkms autoinstall on 6.5.0-14-generic/x86_64 succeeded for nvidia virtualbox
dkms autoinstall on 6.5.0-14-generic/x86_64 failed for ch340(10)
Error! One or more modules failed to install during autoinstall.
Refer to previous errors for more information.
 * dkms: autoinstall for kernel 6.5.0-14-generic
   ...fail!
run-parts: /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms exited with return code 11
dpkg: errore nell'elaborare il pacchetto linux-headers-6.5.0-14-generic (--confi
gure):
 il sottoprocesso installato pacchetto linux-headers-6.5.0-14-generic script pos
t-installation ha restituito lo stato di errore 1
dpkg: problemi con le dipendenze impediscono la configurazione di linux-headers-
generic:
 linux-headers-generic dipende da linux-headers-6.5.0-14-generic; tuttavia:
  Il pacchetto linux-headers-6.5.0-14-generic non è ancora configurato.

dpkg: errore nell'elaborare il pacchetto linux-headers-generic (--configure):
 problemi con le dipendenze - lasciato non configurato
Configurazione di linux-image-6.5.0-14-generic (6.5.0-14.14)...
Segnalazione apport non scritta poiché il messaggio di errore indica la presenza
 di un fallimento precedente.
                             dpkg: problemi con le dipendenze impediscono la con
figurazione di linux-headers-generic-hwe-22.04:
 linux-headers-generic-hwe-22.04 dipende da linux-headers-6.5.0-14-generic; tutt
avia:
  Il pacchetto linux-headers-6.5.0-14-generic non è ancora configurato.

dpkg: errore nell'elaborare il pacchetto linux-headers-generic-hwe-22.04 (--conf
igure):
 problemi con le dipendenze - lasciato non configurato
Segnalazione apport non scritta poiché il messaggio di errore indica la presenza
 di un fallimento precedente.
                             Segnalazione apport non scritta poiché è stato ragg
iunto il valore massimo di MaxReports
                                     Segnalazione apport non scritta poiché è st
ato raggiunto il valore massimo di MaxReports
                                             dpkg: problemi con le dipendenze im
pediscono la configurazione di linux-generic-hwe-22.04:
 linux-generic-hwe-22.04 dipende da linux-headers-generic-hwe-22.04 (= 6.5.0.14.
16); tuttavia:
  Il pacchetto linux-headers-generic-hwe-22.04 non è ancora configurato.

dpkg: errore nell'elaborare il pacchetto linux-generic-hwe-22.04 (--configure):
 problemi con le dipendenze - lasciato non configurato
dpkg: problemi con le dipendenze impediscono la configurazione di linux-generic:
 linux-generic dipende da linux-headers-generic (= 6.5.0.14.16); tuttavia:
  Il pacchetto linux-headers-generic non è ancora configurato.

dpkg: errore nell'elaborare il pacchetto linux-generic (--configure):
 problemi con le dipendenze - lasciato non configurato
Elaborazione dei trigger per dbus (1.14.10-1ubuntu1)...
Elaborazione dei trigger per mailcap (3.70+nmu1ubuntu1)...
Elaborazione dei trigger per desktop-file-utils (0.26-1ubuntu5)...
Elaborazione dei trigger per hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2)...
Elaborazione dei trigger per gnome-menus (3.36.0-1.1ubuntu1)...
Si sono verificati degli errori nell'elaborazione:
 linux-headers-6.5.0-14-generic
 linux-headers-generic
 linux-headers-generic-hwe-22.04
 linux-generic-hwe-22.04
 linux-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I see a lot of errors but I'm able to understand which one is the root cause. My wild guess is:

```
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for ch340: 1.0.0 not found
```

I read [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1467898/dkms-errors-when-updating-upgrading-ubuntu) question but `sudo dpkg -l | grep ch340` returns nothing. While `sudo dpkg -l | grep dkms` returns:

```
ii  dkms                                          3.0.11-1ubuntu10                           all          Dynamic Kernel Module System (DKMS)
ii  nvidia-dkms-470                               470.223.02-0ubuntu0.23.10.1                amd64        NVIDIA DKMS package
ii  virtualbox-dkms                               7.0.10-dfsg-3                              amd64        x86 virtualization solution - kernel module sources for dkms
```

Can you help me to understand how to fix this issue?

### UPDATE

```
$ dkms status
ch340/1.0.0: added
nvidia/470.223.02, 6.5.0-10-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia/470.223.02, 6.5.0-14-generic, x86_64: installed
virtualbox/7.0.10, 6.5.0-10-generic, x86_64: installed
virtualbox/7.0.10, 6.5.0-14-generic, x86_64: installed

$ tree /var/lib/dkms/
/var/lib/dkms/
├── ch340
│   └── 1.0.0
│       ├── build
│       │   ├── ch340.c
│       │   ├── ch340.mod
│       │   ├── dkms.conf
│       │   ├── Dockerfile
│       │   ├── Makefile
│       │   ├── make.log
│       │   └── README.md
│       └── source -> /usr/src/ch340-1.0.0
├── nvidia
│   ├── 470.223.02
│   │   ├── 6.5.0-10-generic
│   │   │   └── x86_64
│   │   │       ├── log
│   │   │       │   └── make.log
│   │   │       └── module
│   │   │           ├── nvidia-drm.ko.zst
│   │   │           ├── nvidia.ko.zst
│   │   │           ├── nvidia-modeset.ko.zst
│   │   │           ├── nvidia-peermem.ko.zst
│   │   │           └── nvidia-uvm.ko.zst
│   │   ├── 6.5.0-14-generic
│   │   │   └── x86_64
│   │   │       ├── log
│   │   │       │   └── make.log
│   │   │       └── module
│   │   │           ├── nvidia-drm.ko.zst
│   │   │           ├── nvidia.ko.zst
│   │   │           ├── nvidia-modeset.ko.zst
│   │   │           ├── nvidia-peermem.ko.zst
│   │   │           └── nvidia-uvm.ko.zst
│   │   └── source -> /usr/src/nvidia-470.223.02
│   ├── kernel-6.5.0-10-generic-x86_64 -> 470.223.02/6.5.0-10-generic/x86_64
│   └── kernel-6.5.0-14-generic-x86_64 -> 470.223.02/6.5.0-14-generic/x86_64
└── virtualbox
    ├── 7.0.10
    │   ├── 6.5.0-10-generic
    │   │   └── x86_64
    │   │       ├── log
    │   │       │   └── make.log
    │   │       └── module
    │   │           ├── vboxdrv.ko.zst
    │   │           ├── vboxnetadp.ko.zst
    │   │           └── vboxnetflt.ko.zst
    │   ├── 6.5.0-14-generic
    │   │   └── x86_64
    │   │       ├── log
    │   │       │   └── make.log
    │   │       └── module
    │   │           ├── vboxdrv.ko.zst
    │   │           ├── vboxnetadp.ko.zst
    │   │           └── vboxnetflt.ko.zst
    │   └── source -> /usr/src/virtualbox-7.0.10
    ├── kernel-6.5.0-10-generic-x86_64 -> 7.0.10/6.5.0-10-generic/x86_64
    └── kernel-6.5.0-14-generic-x86_64 -> 7.0.10/6.5.0-14-generic/x86_64

31 directories, 27 files

$ df -h
File system     Dim. Usati Dispon. Uso% Montato su
tmpfs           782M  2,3M    780M   1% /run
/dev/sda3       183G   38G    136G  22% /
tmpfs           3,9G   76K    3,9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5,0M  8,0K    5,0M   1% /run/lock
efivarfs        128K   48K     76K  39% /sys/firmware/efi/efivars
/dev/sda4       260G   45G    202G  19% /home
/dev/sda1        93M  6,1M     87M   7% /boot/efi
tmpfs           782M   80K    782M   1% /run/user/1000
```

### UPDATE 2

Looking at `/var/lib/dkms/ch340/1.0.0/build/make.log` I found:

```
/var/lib/dkms/ch340/1.0.0/build/ch340.c: At top level:
/var/lib/dkms/ch340/1.0.0/build/ch340.c:675:30: error: initialization of ‘void (*)(struct tty_struct *, struct usb_serial_port *, const struct ktermios *)’ from incompatible pointer >
  675 |         .set_termios       = ch340_set_termios,
      |                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/var/lib/dkms/ch340/1.0.0/build/ch340.c:675:30: note: (near initialization for ‘ch340_device.set_termios’)
/var/lib/dkms/ch340/1.0.0/build/ch340.c:676:30: error: initialization of ‘int (*)(struct tty_struct *, int)’ from incompatible pointer type ‘void (*)(struct tty_struct *, int)’ [-Wer>
  676 |         .break_ctl         = ch340_break_ctl,
      |                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/var/lib/dkms/ch340/1.0.0/build/ch340.c:676:30: note: (near initialization for ‘ch340_device.break_ctl’)
/var/lib/dkms/ch340/1.0.0/build/ch340.c:682:30: error: initialization of ‘void (*)(struct usb_serial_port *)’ from incompatible pointer type ‘int (*)(struct usb_serial_port *)’ [-Wer>
  682 |         .port_remove       = ch340_port_remove,
      |                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/var/lib/dkms/ch340/1.0.0/build/ch340.c:682:30: note: (near initialization for ‘ch340_device.port_remove’)
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[3]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:251: /var/lib/dkms/ch340/1.0.0/build/ch340.o] Errore 1
make[2]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-6.5.0-14-generic/Makefile:2037: /var/lib/dkms/ch340/1.0.0/build] Errore 2
make[1]: *** [Makefile:234: __sub-make] Errore 2
make[1]: uscita dalla directory «/usr/src/linux-headers-6.5.0-14-generic»
make: *** [Makefile:5: default] Errore 2
```

I guess this is the reason why it does not find the binary: it does not build! How is it possible an official Ubuntu application has errors in the code!?

Comment: Please add `dkms status` and `tree /var/lib/dkms/` to your question. You has 3  metapackages for kernels/headers on your system. Also `df -h` pleases.

Comment: @nobody done! thanks

Answer (score 1):

Okay
please in file

```
/usr/src/ch340-1.0.0/dkms.conf
```

change

```
AUTOINSTALL="yes"
```

to

```
AUTOINSTALL="no"
```

Then we remove the module from dkms tree.

```
sudo dkms remove ch340/1.0.0 -k --all
```

The big question is where comes the folder from.

Please mv folder and only this folder in your $HOME

```
sudo mv /var/lib/dkms/ch340/ $HOME
```

Then please

```
sudo apt -f install
```

And a sidenote decide for 1 kerneltree.

It seems you use hw-edge at least the modules for virtualbox and nvidia are build and installed for this kerneltree.So clean up linux-generic and linux-generic-hwe-22.04 kernel tree by deinstalling it.

The meta package for this kerneltree is

```
linux-generic-hwe-22.04-edge
```

edit:

```
sudo apt purge linux-generic linux-image-generic linux-headers-generic linux-generic-hwe-22.04 linux-image-generic-hwe-22.04 linux-headers-generic-hwe-22.04
```

Then please install metapackages for your kernel.

```
sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-22.04-edge
```

And

```
sudo apt autopurge
```

Comment: The first part worked well! Just for completeness I could not able to move the `/var/lib/dkms/ch340/` since it was not there after removing the module.

Comment: Would you please clarify how to "decide" and clean up the other kerneltrees? I don't know them and I don't recall I installed three of them!

Comment: @Mark expand answer.