# After I fixed a kernel panic I keep getting "E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)"

Tags: package-management, kernel, dpkg, gcc

So I have been getting this error after I had a kernel panic and decided to follow this article:
https://www.geekswarrior.com/2019/07/solved-how-to-fix-kernel-panic-on-linux.html
From what I have gathered, it seems to be a problem with the Linux package handler
I cant sudo apt get anything without it returning this error, and neither can I execute the commands that other articles say fix this error without also returning the error.

Thanks for any help in advance!

By the way, when it said "checking for nproc... (cached) yes" a ton of times, I removed it in the message because it was just repeating and exceeding the character limit.

````
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 52 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up linux-image-6.2.0-20-generic (6.2.0-20.20) ...
Setting up linux-headers-6.2.0-20-generic (6.2.0-20.20) ...
/etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 6.2.0-20-generic
Sign command: /usr/bin/kmodsign
Signing key: /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.priv
Public certificate (MOK): /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.der

Running the pre_build script:
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking for gcc... x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-12
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether the compiler supports GNU C... yes
checking whether x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-12 accepts -g... yes
checking for x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-12 option to enable C11 features... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-12 -E
checking kernel source directory... /usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-20-generic
checking kernel build directory... /usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-20-generic
checking kernel source version... 6.2.0-20-generic
checking kernel file name for module symbols... Module.symvers
checking for linux/overflow.h... yes
checking for linux/sched/mm.h... yes
checking for linux/sched/task.h... yes
checking for linux/sched/signal.h... yes
checking for linux/nospec.h... yes
checking for linux/bits.h... yes
checking for linux/io-64-nonatomic-lo-hi.h... yes
checking for asm/set_memory.h... yes
checking for asm/fpu/api.h... yes
checking for uapi/linux/sched/types.h... yes
checking for linux/compiler_attributes.h... yes
checking for linux/dma-fence.h... yes
checking for linux/dma-resv.h... yes
checking for linux/mmap_lock.h... yes
checking for linux/pci-p2pdma.h... yes
checking for linux/dma-attrs.h... no
checking for linux/mem_encrypt.h... yes
checking for linux/dma-buf-map.h... no
checking for linux/iosys-map.h... yes
checking for linux/stdarg.h... yes
checking for linux/dma-fence-chain.h... yes
checking for linux/xarray.h... yes
checking for linux/container_of.h... yes
checking for linux/cc_platform.h... yes
checking for linux/processor.h... yes
checking for linux/dma-map-ops.h... yes
checking for drm/drm_backport.h... no
checking for drm/amdgpu_pciid.h... no
checking for drm/drm_auth.h... yes
checking for drm/drm_irq.h... no
checking for drm/drm_connector.h... yes
checking for drm/drm_encoder.h... yes
checking for drm/drm_plane.h... yes
checking for drm/drm_print.h... yes
checking for drm/drm_drv.h... yes
checking for drm/drm_file.h... yes
checking for drm/drm_debugfs.h... yes
checking for drm/drm_ioctl.h... yes
checking for drm/drm_vblank.h... yes
checking for drm/drm_device.h... yes
checking for drm/drm_gem_framebuffer_helper.h... yes
checking for drm/drm_hdcp.h... no
checking for drm/drm_audio_component.h... yes
checking for drm/drm_util.h... yes
checking for drm/drm_atomic_uapi.h... yes
checking for drm/drm_probe_helper.h... yes
checking for drm/drmP.h... no
checking for drm/task_barrier.h... yes
checking for drm/drm_managed.h... yes
checking for drm/amd_asic_type.h... yes
checking for drm/drm_aperture.h... yes
checking for drm/dp/drm_dp_helper.h... no
checking for drm/dp/drm_dp_mst_helper.h... no
checking for drm/display/drm_dp_helper.h... yes
checking for drm/display/drm_dp_mst_helper.h... yes
checking for drm/display/drm_dsc.h... yes
checking for drm/display/drm_dsc_helper.h... yes
checking for drm/display/drm_hdmi_helper.h... yes
checking for drm/display/drm_hdcp_helper.h... yes
checking for drm/display/drm_hdcp.h... yes
checking for drm/display/drm_dp.h... yes
checking for drm/drm_dsc.h... no
checking for linux/pgtable.h... yes
checking for drm/drm_simple_kms_helper.h... yes
checking for drm/drm_damage_helper.h... yes
checking for nproc... yes
checking for supported chips... done
checking for nproc... (cached) yes
checking for module configuration... done
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating config/config.h

Building module:
Cleaning build area...(bad exit status: 2)
make -j16 KERNELRELEASE=6.2.0-20-generic -j16 TTM_NAME=amdttm SCHED_NAME=amd-sched -C /lib/modules/6.2.0-20-generic/build M=/var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.18.13-1538762.22.04/build...(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/amdgpu-dkms.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.2.0-20-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.18.13-1538762.22.04/build/make.log for more information.
Error! One or more modules failed to install during autoinstall.
Refer to previous errors for more information.
   ...fail!
run-parts: /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms exited with return code 11
dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-6.2.0-20-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-headers-6.2.0-20-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-headers-generic:
 linux-headers-generic depends on linux-headers-6.2.0-20-generic; however:
  Package linux-headers-6.2.0-20-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic:
 linux-generic depends on linux-headers-generic (= 6.2.0.20.20); however:
  Package linux-headers-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                           Processing triggers for linux-image-6.2.0-20-generic (6.2.0-20.20) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 6.2.0-20-generic
Sign command: /usr/bin/kmodsign
Signing key: /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.priv
Public certificate (MOK): /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.der

Running the pre_build script:
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking for gcc... x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-12
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether the compiler supports GNU C... yes
checking whether x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-12 accepts -g... yes
checking for x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-12 option to enable C11 features... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-12 -E
checking kernel source directory... /usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-20-generic
checking kernel build directory... /usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-20-generic
checking kernel source version... 6.2.0-20-generic
checking kernel file name for module symbols... Module.symvers
checking for linux/overflow.h... yes
checking for linux/sched/mm.h... yes
checking for linux/sched/task.h... yes
checking for linux/sched/signal.h... yes
checking for linux/nospec.h... yes
checking for linux/bits.h... yes
checking for linux/io-64-nonatomic-lo-hi.h... yes
checking for asm/set_memory.h... yes
checking for asm/fpu/api.h... yes
checking for uapi/linux/sched/types.h... yes
checking for linux/compiler_attributes.h... yes
checking for linux/dma-fence.h... yes
checking for linux/dma-resv.h... yes
checking for linux/mmap_lock.h... yes
checking for linux/pci-p2pdma.h... yes
checking for linux/dma-attrs.h... no
checking for linux/mem_encrypt.h... yes
checking for linux/dma-buf-map.h... no
checking for linux/iosys-map.h... yes
checking for linux/stdarg.h... yes
checking for linux/dma-fence-chain.h... yes
checking for linux/xarray.h... yes
checking for linux/container_of.h... yes
checking for linux/cc_platform.h... yes
checking for linux/processor.h... yes
checking for linux/dma-map-ops.h... yes
checking for drm/drm_backport.h... no
checking for drm/amdgpu_pciid.h... no
checking for drm/drm_auth.h... yes
checking for drm/drm_irq.h... no
checking for drm/drm_connector.h... yes
checking for drm/drm_encoder.h... yes
checking for drm/drm_plane.h... yes
checking for drm/drm_print.h... yes
checking for drm/drm_drv.h... yes
checking for drm/drm_file.h... yes
checking for drm/drm_debugfs.h... yes
checking for drm/drm_ioctl.h... yes
checking for drm/drm_vblank.h... yes
checking for drm/drm_device.h... yes
checking for drm/drm_gem_framebuffer_helper.h... yes
checking for drm/drm_hdcp.h... no
checking for drm/drm_audio_component.h... yes
checking for drm/drm_util.h... yes
checking for drm/drm_atomic_uapi.h... yes
checking for drm/drm_probe_helper.h... yes
checking for drm/drmP.h... no
checking for drm/task_barrier.h... yes
checking for drm/drm_managed.h... yes
checking for drm/amd_asic_type.h... yes
checking for drm/drm_aperture.h... yes
checking for drm/dp/drm_dp_helper.h... no
checking for drm/dp/drm_dp_mst_helper.h... no
checking for drm/display/drm_dp_helper.h... yes
checking for drm/display/drm_dp_mst_helper.h... yes
checking for drm/display/drm_dsc.h... yes
checking for drm/display/drm_dsc_helper.h... yes
checking for drm/display/drm_hdmi_helper.h... yes
checking for drm/display/drm_hdcp_helper.h... yes
checking for drm/display/drm_hdcp.h... yes
checking for drm/display/drm_dp.h... yes
checking for drm/drm_dsc.h... no
checking for linux/pgtable.h... yes
checking for drm/drm_simple_kms_helper.h... yes
checking for drm/drm_damage_helper.h... yes
checking for nproc... yes
checking for supported chips... done
checking for nproc... (cached) yes
checking for module configuration... done
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating config/config.h

Building module:
Cleaning build area...(bad exit status: 2)
make -j16 KERNELRELEASE=6.2.0-20-generic -j16 TTM_NAME=amdttm SCHED_NAME=amd-sched -C /lib/modules/6.2.0-20-generic/build M=/var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.18.13-1538762.22.04/build...(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/amdgpu-dkms.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.2.0-20-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.18.13-1538762.22.04/build/make.log for more information.
Error! One or more modules failed to install during autoinstall.
Refer to previous errors for more information.
   ...fail!
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms exited with return code 11
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-6.2.0-20-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-6.2.0-20-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-headers-6.2.0-20-generic
 linux-headers-generic
 linux-generic
 linux-image-6.2.0-20-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)```
````

Comment: "*it seems to be a problem with the Linux package handler*" That suggests you have not adequately read the output. A lot of good troubleshooting information in there. Go line-by-line, the way it was created. Don't look for the final error message. Look instead for the *initial* error message, and what was happening around that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Package linux-image-generic is not configured yet](https://askubuntu.com/questions/429731/package-linux-image-generic-is-not-configured-yet)