# Software suddenly not starting, doesn't show up in System Monitor

Tags: system-monitor

Specifically, I'm trying to get RStudio to work on Ubuntu 12.04. Yesterday it was working fine, but now when I either click or try to start it from terminal, exactly nothing happens. The prompt returns nothing, the click produces nothing. What could have caused this and how do I fix it?

Comment: RStudio desktop or server? What have you tried already? Help us help you by providing as much information as possible.

Comment: Anything interesting in syslog or dpkg.log?

Comment: Tried dmesg which produced this: [ 1059.142229] type=1400 audit(1399385930.889:31): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" parent=1 profile="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=1057 comm="cupsd" pid=1057 comm="cupsd" capability=36  capname="block_suspend"

Comment: dpkg.log just says rstudio was successfully installed.

Comment: Any updates applied or packages added/removed between yesterday when it worked and today when it didn't?

Comment: Which of these options did you choose on initial install? Desktop or server? https://www.rstudio.com/ide/download/

Comment: Desktop. The only thing I've installed since yesterday is Matlab.

Comment: Re-installed Rstudio now, still not working. Nothing noteworthy in log files apart from that AppArmor thing. I installed the RSQLite package yesterday aswell, I seem to have read somewhere about sqlite/apparmor issues. Will do research on that.

Answer (score 2):

Found the issue.

For some reason, locale issues were causing it. When trying to run r from terminal, there was some locale related error message, so I just generated and reconfigured a new one as described here:

[How do I fix my locale issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162391/how-do-i-fix-my-locale-issue)

Suddenly RStudio was working fine.

Comment: would you please edit to include the locale related error message in your question and what you did to fix it in your answer? In this way you will be helping others who have this problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try putting apparmor in complain mode. this may allow Rstudio to work as well as give clues as to why it's throwing that DENIED at you.

see [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingApparmor)