# how to fix locale error

Tags: 14.04, kubuntu, locale

I just did a fresh install of ubuntu using `debootstrap`.  When I do `sudo aptitude upgrade`, I get this error message:

```
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = "en_US:en",
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LANG = "en_US.ISO-8859-1"
are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
```

Can someone please tell me how to resolve this issue?  I see a lot of postings similar to this online but none of them seems to resolve the problem.

I am using `Ubuntu 14.04 LTS`.  Thanks.

---

FYI:

```
$ locale -a
C
C.UTF-8
en_AG
en_AG.utf8
en_AU.utf8
en_BW.utf8
en_CA.utf8
en_DK.utf8
en_GB.utf8
en_HK.utf8
en_IE.utf8
en_IN
en_IN.utf8
en_NG
en_NG.utf8
en_NZ.utf8
en_PH.utf8
en_SG.utf8
en_US.iso88591
en_US.utf8
en_ZA.utf8
en_ZM
en_ZM.utf8
en_ZW.utf8
POSIX
```

and

```
$ locale
LANG=en_US.ISO-8859-1
LANGUAGE=en_US:en
LC_CTYPE="en_US.ISO-8859-1"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.ISO-8859-1"
LC_TIME="en_US.ISO-8859-1"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.ISO-8859-1"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.ISO-8859-1"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.ISO-8859-1"
LC_PAPER="en_US.ISO-8859-1"
LC_NAME="en_US.ISO-8859-1"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.ISO-8859-1"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.ISO-8859-1"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.ISO-8859-1"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.ISO-8859-1"
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: This was answered here already http://askubuntu.com/questions/162391/how-do-i-fix-my-locale-issue Summary: define LC_ALL on /etc/default/locale

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `debootstrap` doesn't create a locale. So we use something else as a locale. Use this command:

```
sudo locale-gen en_US.ISO-8859-1
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Nope, `aptitude` is valid too. Your answer will not give any changes to the OP.

Comment: While that may solve the locale error, it gives you a system with latin1 encoding, which is not suitable on Ubuntu.

Comment: Also, in `~/.kde.env/setlocale.sh`, you set `export LANG=en_US.UTF-8`

Answer (score 11):

An Ubuntu desktop should be set up with UTF-8 encoding. For some reason your system tries to set the latin1 locale en_US.ISO-8859-1. You should really change that.

Maybe the setting takes place in `/etc/default/locale`.

Whereever it happens, change it to

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

or else you will encounter various locale related surprises.

Comment: Are you sure that's the one to use?  How do you know?

Comment: @user1527227: Well, almost. ;) Because AFAIK `en_US.UTF-8` comes pre-generated on every Ubuntu desktop. But you can easily check it by running the `locale -a` command. It would be good if you edited the question and added the output of that command.

Comment: i added the info you requested.

Comment: @user1527227: Ok, and there we can see `en_US.utf8` in the `locale -a` output. My advice to change from `en_US.ISO-8859-1` to `en_US.UTF-8` stands.

Comment: Thank you.  Do you know how to exactly do that? I do not see `/etc/default/locale`.  Can I just run `sudo locale-gen en_US.utf8`?

Comment: @user1527227: No, no, the locale is already generated. Now the configuration should be changed to make use of it. Probably the best way is to go to `System Settings -> Language Support`, change the selected language item, change it back to English (United States), and then click the "Apply System-Wide" button.

Comment: I'm using `ubuntu 14.04 LTE amd64`.  I don't see `Language Support` in `System Settings`.

Comment: @user1527227: That's strange. (I suppose you mean LTS.) Sounds like your system is not complete. You can make sure it gets completed by running `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`

Comment: Oh I have `ubuntu` but i'm using `KDE` :).  Do you know how to change it from there?

Comment: @user1527227: Well, no. This is a page where the most common config files for setting environment variables are mentioned: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables

Comment: I just found the command `update-locale LANG=en_US.UTF-8`. Probably this is the way which works also on future releases since keyboard/locale config is changing all the time in new Ubuntu releases. The command also checks if the values are valid...

Comment: @DanielAlder: Right, that's a command line tool to edit `/etc/default/locale`, which I should have thought of. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

A permanent solution for locale issue is to export the locale variables in your `~/.bash_profile`.  You can also use `/etc/profile` file instead of `.bash_profile` to have the change take effect for all users on the system.

```
echo "export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
" >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Don't forget to start a new shell or to manually `source  ~/.bash_profile`.

Comment: Just a heads-up -- I wouldn't normally approve an edit that removed a link to your blog, but you did not disclose that you were linking to your personal content in your post.  You can add the link back in if you'd like, but please make sure to review [Expected Behavior](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/behavior), specifically, *"if you mention your product, website, etc. in your question or answer, you must disclose your affiliation in your post."*  Thanks!

Comment: Also note that, while I didn't test it, I'm fairly confident that your blog post has an error.  You can't `source` from within an *executed* script (e.g. `./set_locale.sh` as your blog states).  The new values will not take effect in the current shell if you do.  You would need to source the script itself (e.g. `source set_locale.sh`)

Answer (score 4):

This works for me.

1. `export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8`
2. `export LANG=en_US.UTF-8`
3. `export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8`
4. `sudo locale-gen en_US.UTF-8`
5. `sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales`

Comment: is your working permanent to fix the `locale` issue?

Answer (score 1):

Add `LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"` to `/etc/environment` and then restart the instance/machine

For more info visit this blog

http://www.pixelninja.me/how-to-fix-invalid-locale-setting-in-ubuntu-14-04-in-the-cloud/

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me is as follows:

`export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
sudo locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales`

For a permanent solution you can put

`export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8`

in your `.zshrc` or `.bashrc`

Ref

1. https://jee-appy.blogspot.com/2016/02/set-locale-on-ubuntu-permanent-solution.html
2. https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Perl_warning_Setting_locale_failed_in_Debian