# error in installing mongo in virtual machine

Tags: virtualbox, mongodb

I try to install mongo using mongo documentation: [Install MongoDB on Ubuntu](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/) no errors were mentioned during the installation. But when I run the `mongo` command following error was displayed in the terminal.

> Failed global initialization: BadValue Invalid or no user locale set. Please ensure LANG and/or LC_* environment variables are set correctly

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Looks like your [`locale`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Locale) settings are broken or non-existent on that VM, or at least that session on that VM.  One of MongoDB's dependencies ([boost](http://www.boost.org/)) will fail when a locale is not correctly set (see [SERVER-9032](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-9032)).  For reference, before the change in SERVER-9032 this problem still happened but looked [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19668570/1148648).

Sometimes logging out and back in can fix it (only broken for current session), or you can try running `sudo locale-gen` to make sure generation is successful.

In the meantime, as a workaround to get `mongo` (or `mongod` etc.) running, just set your `LC_ALL` variable manually before starting the program:

```
export LC_ALL=C
mongo
```

Comment: Are we supposed to configure the locale when creating a new VM?

Comment: Depends on how you do your OS install - most setup flows/UIs are going to take care of this for you by asking you where you are and what language you use - if you go old school you would have to potentially do this yourself, but I'm fairly sure I haven't seen a locale selection screen for years.  Basically, it's not unreasonable to expect this to be done for you and you should only hear about it when it is screwed up in some way.

Comment: Thanks, it was a CentOS Vm so i think I need an Ansible task for that!

Answer (score 15):

I also tried installing MongoDB on Ubuntu 12.04 and got the same error on a virtual machine (XEN). For me, modifiying `/etc/default/locale` did the trick. I got it working with these settings:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

Or, another working config would be (mind the quotes and the :en):

```
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LANGUAGE="en_US:en"
LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
```

[Adam C's workaround with `export`](https://askubuntu.com/a/537324/354406) also helped and is probably the more elaborate answer.

Answer (score 4):

Though the other answers provided here solve the problem correctly the following Stackoverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27292368) brought me to what the actual issue is when having MongoDB installed in a Vagrant VM and getting the above error:

> This problem appears because host machine put locale to guest via ssh.

Thus the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34582489) suggesting to override the host locale within the Vagrantfile solves it permanently with just a line:

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|

    ENV['LC_ALL']="en_US.UTF-8"

    # ...

end
```

Also note the comments about that it **does not** modify the actual LC_ALL value on the host.

Answer (score 1):

Based on this https://askubuntu.com/a/227513/59618 you can just:

```
$ sudo locale-gen "en_US.UTF-8"
Generating locales...
  en_US.UTF-8... done
Generation complete.

$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
Generating locales...
  en_US.UTF-8... up-to-date
Generation complete.
```

Comment: didn't work for me