# How to find manpage package corresponding to a specific executable?

Tags: manpage

After installing Ubuntu 14.10 Desktop 64-bit from scratch on a laptop, I tried to fix the installer bug whereby the locales are not set up properly by default.

I then found a possible fix to that installer bug at https://askubuntu.com/a/227513/340383 which calls for executing `local-gen` under sudo. Wanting to know more about what local-gen does, I executed `man local-gen` and got:

```
No manual entry for local-gen
```

So I have two questions:

1. How do I start with a name of an executable, such as `local-gen` in this case, and find out the corresponding package to install the corresponding man pages?
2. How do I find the man page package specifically for local-gen?

Comment: It's called `locale-gen`, I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is

```
locale-gen
```

and `man locale-gen` gives:

```
DESCRIPTION
       Compiled  locale  files  take  about 50MB of disk space, and most users
       only need few locales.  In order to save disk  space,  compiled  locale
       files  are not distributed in the locales package, but...
```

<sub>Steeldriver did comment before I answered. [I believe we hit upon it at the same time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XiGRb.png). I did not mean to plagiarize.</sub>

Comment: Thanks but `man local-gen` gives `man: can't set the local; make sure $LC_* and $LANG are correct` followed by `No manual entry for local-gen`.   Hmmmm. I wonder if we have a chicken-and-the-egg problem here with the first message dealing with locales?

Comment: I said `locale-gen`. There is an `e` on the end of it.

Comment: Ah! Shot myself in the foot with a missing "e"! How embarrasing. Marking your answer as the one. Thanks Tim.