# Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory

Tags: 12.04, locale

I have the exact question as this but there's no solution. I tried but it doesn't work

[How do I fix my locale issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162391/how-do-i-fix-my-locale-issue)

```
$ locale
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE=UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=

$ locale -a
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
C
C.UTF-8
en_US.utf8
POSIX
```

Is this because of en_US.UTF-8 and en_US.utf8 mismatch?

How to fix?

Comment: Did you read this http://askubuntu.com/a/229512/387382?

Answer (score 108):

This same problem (LC_CTYPE=UTF-8, which is wrong) can happen when you login over ssh from a Mac to a linux box, and your terminal  automatically sets environment variables. There's a checkbox for that. Uncheck it, and you're good to go.

In iTerm it's in the profile -> Terminal tab.

In Terminal, it's in the Terminal -> Preferences -> Profiles -> Advanced tab.

Comment: in iTerm disable the checkbox "Preferences>Profiles>Default>Terminal>Environment>Set locale variables automatically"

Comment: -1: While this might work, it's extremely invasive. You also potentially affect the behaviour of your local terminal as well as the behaviour of every host you connect to. While your findings are true, it's a better idea to use the ssh_config to make it not send the LC_* for hosts known to have problems.

Comment: Can you please add your own answer, extending it with more explanation as to why this potentially affects behaviour of your local terminal, and how to tell ssh_config not to send LC_*. Because you just -1 my answer without real explanation.

Comment: If you're connecting from MacOS using Terminal, go to Terminal Settings>Advanced and uncheck "Set locale environment variables at startup".

Comment: What seems to happen is: on your local system, you have some locale installed, then you ssh to another system, that doesn't have this locale installed. The terminal client will tell the remote system what your locale is, and the remote system will fail to answer in the requested language. You have two ways to remedy this: either you change, what is requested or you add the requested locale to the remote system (which requires root access).

Comment: Thanks, it's absolutely fit in my case. 
In detail, it solved following command 
> export LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
, but I think your solution is much clear.

Answer (score 93):

Open terminal and fire the below command:

```
export LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
```

Comment: This works, but why?

Comment: This doesn't solve anything since the variable is destroyed at the end of the session..

Comment: Please see:
https://ss64.com/bash/export.html
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Locale

Comment: Great solution in so little words. Lol!

Comment: When exporting this var I get: `-bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8)`

Comment: To avoid ```-bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8)``` error you may need to reboot the server.

Comment: For those who want to keep the setting between sessions, add that line to your ```.bashrc``` file.

Comment: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8): No such file or directory

Answer (score 68):

Generate missing locales and select your desired default with:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

Comment: Actually only `sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales` is necessary since it uses locale-gen.

Comment: This should be the actual answer to the problem, and only one

Comment: Thank you for this!

Comment: I'm running WSL2. After running this command I get a list of errors, the first one being `perl: warning: Setting locale failed.` [Thamme Gowda](https://askubuntu.com/a/1486614/1297632)'s answer fixed it for me.

Answer (score 56):

I had the similar issue and added the below lines in my `/etc/default/locale` file:

```
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
```

I got this from this post: [How do I fix my locale issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162391/how-do-i-fix-my-locale-issue)

Comment: Well, by doing so you end up with a very messy locale configuration. `/etc/environment` is not intended for setting locales in Ubuntu; `/etc/default/locale` is. Also, in case of a desktop you should never, ever set `LC_ALL` persistently. Your way will make the UIs for controlling language/locale settings on a desktop, such as Language Support, useless.

Comment: This actually works. After a reboot.

Comment: Logout and Login, it should work

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me, but as @GunnarHjalmarsson pointed out, it breaks all the desktop's settings (i.e. can no longer change the date format, etc).  I've spent the past 4 hours trying everything I can find, but nothing fixes the issue without breaking the language settings UI.  Is there some proper solution - that doesn't involve the nuclear approach of setting LC_LL in /etc/default/locale, per this solution?

Comment: @Metal450: Drop the `LC_ALL` line. It's not needed. The `LC_CTYPE` line is sufficient to work around the impact from some remote Mac device.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Thanks for the quick reply - my issue doesn't involve any Mac (I'm running Kubuntu locally).  If I drop LC_ALL, the problem returns - it's *only* fixed if I include the LC_ALL (which, of course, nukes all other locale/format settings in the process).

Comment: @Metal450: Then your problem is most likely something quite different than the problem the OP of this question reported. You may want to submit an own question. If you do, don't forget to mention that you are on Kubuntu.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Thanks - after several hours of trial and error, I was able to mysteriously fix it by just removing & reinstalling the "locales" package.  Strange!  But thanks for the replies :)

Comment: This did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 22):

This commands saved my life

```
echo "LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8" | sudo tee -a /etc/environment
echo "en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8" | sudo tee -a /etc/locale.gen
echo "LANG=en_US.UTF-8" | sudo tee -a /etc/locale.conf
sudo locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
```

Comment: Files are opened before `sudo`.  The redirects won't work unless you were already root.

Comment: @MartinThornton, the issue is fixed :)

Comment: finally! THIS WORKS! all the rest doesnt (Raspberry PI)

Comment: this one worked when i was in the root user

Comment: This was the only answer to work for me when perl gave locale warnings on raspbian.

Answer (score 16):

```
export LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

Comment: I was running a near-clean Vultr instance with issues as in the question, looked into the environment vars and everything looked alright. However, `sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales` did something that must have been missing. My ssh sessions are now OK. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

The output from the `locale` command indicates that you have this incorrect line in your environment:

```
LC_CTYPE="UTF-8"
```

("UTF-8" is not a valid locale name.)

It typically comes from `/etc/default/locale`. Please remove that line, if it's there, and relogin.

If it does not come from there, it can come from your shell configuration, or if you're logged in remotely via SSH, from the configuration of the client machine.

Comment: Do I  change LC_CTYPE to utf8 ?

Comment: @Lucas: No, that would be just as bad. Since LANG is set, you can simply remove the whole line which begins with LC_CTYPE.

Comment: If you want to set LC_TYPE, you should also set it to "en_US.UTF-8".

Comment: If it comes from the configuration of the client machine, you can add the locale on the server with `dpkg-reconfigure locales`.

Answer (score 4):

The /etc/default/locale file can have additional (but unnecessary) lines:
Example file can look like this:

```
#  File generated by update-locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE="en_IN:en
```

To sort out and successfully generate and reconfigure locales, remove or comment out all lines from this file except:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

The file should finally look like:

```
#  File generated by update-locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
# LANGUAGE="en_IN:en
```

After this, run `dpkg-reconfigure locales`, select en_US.UTF-8 when prompted for selecting the locale, and you should be good to go. You'll receive a `Generation complete.` message when the process is complete.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem on Pi-OS bullseye. What worked for me was editing `/etc/default/locale`.
I've added the line (at least for german):

```
LC_ALL=de_DE.UTF-8
```

Then re-login and simply

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

did the job - no errors after this

Comment: Only Ubuntu and official derivatives are on topic here.

Comment: Well okay. But maybe that will work on Ubuntu as well as on pi-os because of the 'same roots' - may you have tested it?

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me when I used `mosh` from ubuntu 22.04 client (WSL2) to another ubuntu 22.04 (server). The above answers didn't fix the problem; what actually fixed it was:

```bash
sudo apt install locales-all
```

---

Long version: I tried the above answers but got `No such file or directory` error. See:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LANGUAGE = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_ALL = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_CTYPE = "C.UTF-8",
        LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
Generating locales (this might take a while)...
Generation complete.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ sudo export LC_All=C.UTF-8 (you should use it)
$ sudo update-locale
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to cause this myself when migrating home directory dot files to a new machine, and I failed to identify the cause for a while on account of searching files for `LC_` but not `LOC`.

The `~/.bashrc` file I copied had the following:

```
export LOCPATH=/var/guix/profiles/per-user/root/guix-profile/lib/locale
```

(the particular value here was on account of prior experiments with GNU Guix on the old machine; but the relevant fact is simply that the environment variable was set to a now-invalid path.)

This resulted in the following error when running various programs:

```
Warning: locale not supported by C library, locale unchanged
```

And these errors when running `locale`:

```
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
```

Removing (or commenting out) the `LOCPATH` line resolved my issues.

Answer (score 0):

After trying all kinds of things to fix this it finally clicked to me - what if the problem was on the other side of the scp? You see I was experiencing this when I tried to scp a file to my server in the cloud. Both running Ubuntu. Now I tried all of these things above like setting LC_ALL and locale, etc. but none worked. It was only after it hit me to do similar things on the server-side that I fixed this.

So I ssh'ed into my server and ran:

```
sudo pkg-reconfigure locales
```

and now when I scp from my desktop at home to my server in the cloud I don't see this locale errors anymore.

Answer (score -1):

just run the following:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

it will generate all locates,then set the default to US:

```
export LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
```

Comment: that's not related. Once you `exported` the variable, you still have to regenerate the locale.