# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Software Updater not responding!

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, updates, update-manager

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I was updating the software on my PC through the Software Updater. It downloaded all the packages but unfortunately during the installation process it stopped responding from the last 3 hours. Please suggest the safest possible way to get out of this situation.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot set LC\_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory](http://askubuntu.com/questions/599808/cannot-set-lc-ctype-to-default-locale-no-such-file-or-directory) and [How do I fix my locale issue?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162391/how-do-i-fix-my-locale-issue)

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem. I killed the process software updater using the System Moniter. Then i restarted the machine and tried to update it again using the terminal. It said that i had to run some command to configure the error.(I don't remember the command) Then the software updater displayed a message saying updates have been already downloaded click to insall. I did so. Then the software updater installed the updates. Problem solved.

note: Some of the steps I described may not be essential. I just described what I did.

Comment: Are you sure your problem was exactly the same? Looks like a locale problem...

Comment: I just experienced the software updater not responding. I couldn't close or expand the window from anywhere in the GUI. What I ended up doing was using pgrep and ps to find and kill the process. After that, I manually updated the APT cache and ran `apt-get upgrade`. That seems to have fixed the problem. I admit that I've not run update-manager after the manual upgrade.