# How to fix Software Updater Issue?

Tags: updates, update-manager, locale

While I update my device using software updater, I am getting following screen and then the updater paused in following screen:

[image]

Here is my locale lists, i.e. list which will display after execute locale command:

[image]

Here is a output of locale -a

[image]

Do anyone have idea how to fix it?

I have already tried the answers given over [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162391/how-do-i-fix-my-locale-issue) stackoverflow question, but it didn't worked for me! :(

Edit:

After applying changes suggested in answer I am getting following error with my update-manager:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: @kos : I added the additional information within the question so that users can identify the actual issue!

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the UTF-8 locale en_IN has not been generated on your system. So then generate it:

```
sudo locale-gen en_IN
```

*Edit:*

The error messages reveal a [bug in Software Updater](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1023421). A workaround to get rid of the error messages is to change LANG to "en_IN.UTF-8".

```
sudo update-locale LANG=en_IN.UTF-8
```

*Edit II:*

To fix the new problem, try these commands:

```
sudo rm -f /var/lib/apt/lists/*
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But, it's not working for me. I run sudo apt-get update and then execute command specified by you in above answer and then run update-manager. Unfortunatly, it still gives same error :(

Comment: @fidato: Can you please run the `locale` command and show us the output by editing your question.

Comment: I had updated the question!

Comment: @fidato: This is weird. Can you also show us the output from the `locale -a` command.

Comment: I had updated the question with output of locale -a command.

Comment: @fidato: Looks as it should... As an experiment, can you please run the command `sudo update-locale LANG=en_IN.UTF-8`. It would update `/etc/default/locale`, and next time you log in, the output from `locale` ought to be different. It would be interesting to know if that makes Software Updater to shut up.

Comment: @fidato: I could reproduce the problem. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: I am getting `Could not recognize package information` error after applying following changes. Do you have any idea regarding above error?

Comment: @fidato: Yes, see my latest edit of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Change `/etc/default/locale` settings to en_IT.UTF-8:

```
LANG="en_IT.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_IT.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_IT.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_IT.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_IT.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_IT.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_IT.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_IT.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_IT.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_IT.UTF-8"
LANGUAGE="en_IT:en"
```