# Python - default locale is not working

Tags: 15.10, python, python3, locale

This is the situation:

```
In [1]: import datetime

In [2]: import locale

In [3]: locale.getlocale()
Out[3]: ('es_ES', 'UTF-8')

In [4]: locale.getdefaultlocale()
Out[4]: ('es_ES', 'UTF-8')

In [5]: datetime.datetime.strftime(datetime.datetime.today(), '%B')
Out[5]: 'July'
```

But the output should be `julio`

If I set the locale, then it works

```
In [6]: locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'es_ES.UTF8')
Out[6]: 'es_ES.UTF8'

In [7]: datetime.datetime.strftime(datetime.datetime.today(), '%B')
Out[7]: 'julio'
```

It happens both in Python2 (2.7.10) and Python3 (3.5.0+)

The system locale is set to Spanish

```
LANG=es_ES.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=es_ES.UTF-8
LC_TIME=es_ES.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=es_ES.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=es_ES.UTF-8
LC_NAME=es_ES.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=es_ES.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=es_ES.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=es_ES.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=es_ES.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

**EDIT:**

Seeing the `locale` output, I realised that LC_ALL was not set. I checked `/etc/default/locale` as it is suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/229512/171961) and I found a mixture of locales.

```
LANG="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
LC_NUMERIC="nl_NL.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="nl_NL.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="nl_NL.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="nl_NL.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="nl_NL.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="nl_NL.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="nl_NL.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="nl_NL.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="nl_NL.UTF-8"
```

Maybe because I updated from 15.04 to 15.10?. Anyway, I filled `LC_ALL` and changed the rest of variables to `es_ES`, executing again `locale-gen` as root. However, even after reboot the system, the situation is the same.

Comment: Here's an issue in the bug tracker: https://bugs.python.org/issue29457

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you should not set `LC_ALL` persistently as a global environment variable. If you do that on a desktop, you make the GUIs for setting languages/locales useless.

As regards your Python program, you need this line:

```
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')
```

It makes the locale, i.e. the output of the `locale` command, effective within the Python program.

Comment: The thing is that I am using a program (not written by me) that uses the `locale` module. However, when it prints information, it does not use the appropriate locale. Checking what could been happening, I discovered the issue I am describing.

Comment: @Manuel: Well, whoever wrote the program, it probably misses the line I suggested.

Comment: You are right, I made a commit with your solution to fix the issue.