# Question marks in Midnight commander

Tags: keyboard, midnight-commander

Today I logged into my Ubuntu server and noticed that Midnight Commander looks different:

[image: strange question marks]

Furthermore, I can't use functional keys (Mac keyboard with Fn key).

I tried to reinstall it, but with no luck. Can anybody help to fix this?

GNU Midnight Commander 4.8.11

Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-53-generic x86_64)

```
$ echo $TERM
ansi
```

I'm using macOS Teminal with oh-my-zsh.

```
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_CTYPE = "ru_RU.UTF-8",
    LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
Generating locales...
  en_US.UTF-8... up-to-date
Generation complete.


$ locale -a
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
C
C.UTF-8
en_US.utf8
POSIX

$ locale
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: Please edit your post to include the output of `echo $TERM` and which application you're using to connect to this server.

Comment: and do a `set TERM=xterm && export TERM` and try mc again ;)

Comment: muru, done!

@Rinzwind, no changes.

Comment: @Mac odd. I can reproduce your problem if I do `TERM=ansi mc`, and it works ok for `TERM=xterm mc`

Comment: @muru `TERM=xterm mc` fixed the problem! But how can I make this behavior permanent?

Comment: When you just open Terminal, is `echo $TERM` `ansi`? Do you have anything in your `.bashrc` or the like which sets `TERM`?

Comment: The problem was in my Terminal theme settings:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/872459/question-marks-in-midnight-commander?noredirect=1#comment1354133_872467

Thank you, @muru and @rinzwind!

Comment: @Mac you should post it as the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was in my Terminal in macOS. I used a "Solarized Dark" theme, which had a setting "Set terminal as" set to `ansi` in "Terminfo" section. The solution is to change it to `xterm-256color`.

Answer (score 9):

TL;DR: *Running `sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales` and picking a UTF-8 locale usually fixes this.*

As [**Joe Hart** said](https://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2007/05/msg01465.html) in reply to [strange "?" characters all over the screen in aptitude, mc and other ncurses programs](https://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2007/05/msg01456.html) (by Deboo ^) on the [debian-user](https://lists.debian.org/debian-user/) mailing list:

> Usually this is a case of a character that is not defined in your
>   current language settings (locale).  You can usually fix this by
>   chosing a UTF8 locale.  dpkg-reconfigure locales should be able to fix
>   your problem.

Specifically, the characters [ncurses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses) uses to draw borders aren't able to be displayed. Perhaps a non-UTF-8 locale got selected or your locales (or locale configuration) is broken. Ensuring you have a [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utf-8) locale installed and selected as the default, and rebuilding your [locales](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Locale), stands a good chance of solving the problem.

Run:

```bash
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

Make sure at least one locale (of an appropriate language and region) *that is marked as `UTF-8`* is selected on the first screen. You will have to scroll down (arrow keys). <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> selects or unselects an item, <kbd>Tab</kbd> switches between the list and the "buttons" below it, and <kbd>Enter</kbd> does roughly what you'd expect (it performs the default action for whatever is selected).

[image: Configuring locales (screenshot), selecting locales to install]

I've selected `en_US.UTF8`, but any UTF-8 locale should work. The first two letters, before the underscore (`_`), represent the language, and the letters right after the underscore represent the country.

Probably it will not look quite like that to you. Like `mc`, `dpkg-reconfigure` may display `*` characters instead of the characters it uses to draw the border. But this is purely cosmetic -- you should still be able to select and configure locales through this utility.

After you've pressed <kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> to "click" the *Ok* button, you'll have to select the default locale. Make sure this is a UTF-8 locale (and that it's of the language and country you want). Move up and down with the arrow keys and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> when you get to the one you want. This will be set as your system's default locale, and all enabled locales will be (re)generated.

[image: Configuring locales (screenshot), choosing a default locale]

In new logins, the problem should be fixed.

<sub>If not, then please run `locale -a` and, separately, `locale`, and edit your question to add the output of each. *Other* users with a similar problem who find this post when searching for help should of course *not* edit this question, but should instead [ask a new question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with a detailed description of their problem as well as a link to this one for context.</sub>

Comment: Thank you for so detailed answer, Eliah! Unfortunately, I still have this problem. Added sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales output into the question.

Comment: @Mac Thanks for the added information. It looks like there is something wrong with your current locale, but apparently not something that `dpkg-reconfigure locales` fixed. (Perhaps the problem is specific to your user account rather than the whole system.) Does the problem still occur when you run `LC_ALL=C mc` instead of `mc`? This would be a workaround rather than a full solution, but may provide some insight into what is going wrong.

Comment: `$ LC_ALL=C mc` gives the same mc with question marks.

I have this problem under all user accounts in the system.

Comment: @Mac Does `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get --purge --reinstall install language-pack-en-base` (and logging out and in) help? If not, are you connecting via SSH? If you have physical access (or another way that's not SSH-based), does the problem occur when you run `mc` that way, or just over SSH? If it's only when you connect through SSH, or you don't know because SSH is the only way you have to connect, then [might you be specifying an unsupported locale in the *client*'s SSH configuration](https://askubuntu.com/a/530829)? Is there a `SendEnv LANG ...` line in the client's `ssh_config`?

Comment: I tried to launch `mc` on my local macOS (without SSH connection to the server) and saw the same problem. Looks like the problem is in my system.

My `~/.ssh/config` on macOS doesn't have `SendEnv LANG LC_*`.

Comment: I finally found a solution! The problem was in my terminal theme "Solarized Dark". On the last tab of theme customization in the section "Terminfo" a setting "Set terminal as" was set to `ansi`, while the default "Basic" theme has this setting is set to `xterm-256color`. I changed it to this option and the problem gone.

Thank you, @eliah-kagan! I would never guess where the problem lies without your help!

Comment: @Mac I'm glad to have contributed! Though muru's idea was closer -- I suggested locale settings (server or client), while muru suggested it could be the terminal type. My answer can remain for others who experience this problem in ncurses programs -- I expect the advice Joe Hart gave on debian-users to help some other Ubuntu users even though it didn't solve the problem for you -- but, [as muru says](https://askubuntu.com/questions/872459/question-marks-in-midnight-commander/872467?noredirect=1#comment1354139_872459), you should post your solution as an answer so it will help other users, too.