# locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory locale

Tags: locale

I've bought a new laptop DELL Inspiron i3 5th gen 3000 series. On my first login, even before restarting, I tried to apply updates and I got the error

```
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
```

It was so nagging to see this because I was using a Compaq laptop earlier and I had the same error, which I could never fix.

Comment: Did you install Ubuntu yourself or was it pre-installed? Anyway, can you please open a terminal window, run the `locale` command, and show us the complete output by editing your question.

Answer (score 13):

Insert into `/etc/default/locale`:

```
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
```

And regarding the missing locales, to generate them: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales`

Comment: Rather than commenting, [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/893586/edit) your post to add the information.

Comment: willdo next time

Answer (score 4):

This one worked for me.

```
sudo -i
locale
export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8; export LANG=en_US.UTF-8; export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8; locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
dpkg-reconfigure locales
reboot
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me (On Ubuntu 14.04 - but probably works on other systems)

```
sudo localedef -v -c -i en_US -f UTF-8 en_US.UTF-8
```