# Fresh installation of ubuntu 16.04 gives me warning about locale. Unable to fix

Tags: locale

I got this on a fresh installation of Ubuntu 16.04 on AWS Lightsail

```
_____________________________________________________________________
WARNING! Your environment specifies an invalid locale.
 The unknown environment variables are:
   LC_CTYPE=UTF-8 LC_ALL=
 This can affect your user experience significantly, including the
 ability to manage packages. You may install the locales by running:

   sudo apt-get install language-pack-UTF-8
     or
   sudo locale-gen UTF-8

To see all available language packs, run:
   apt-cache search "^language-pack-[a-z][a-z]$"
To disable this message for all users, run:
   sudo touch /var/lib/cloud/instance/locale-check.skip
_____________________________________________________________________
```

Then I follow the instructions

```
$ sudo apt-get install language-pack-UTF-8
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package language-pack-UTF-8
```

Then I tried the other one

```
$ sudo locale-gen UTF-8
Error: 'UTF-8' is not a supported language or locale
```

What should I do now?

Comment: I think your LC_CTYPE is incorrect.  See:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/881742/locale-cannot-set-lc-ctype-to-default-locale-no-such-file-or-directory-locale

Comment: dpkg-reconfigure tzdata ?

Answer (score 1):

This is a guess, since I don't know how AWS Lightsail works.

Apparently the `LC_CTYPE` variable has been assigned a value (`"UTF-8"`) which is invalid in Ubuntu. So let's clear that variable.

Open the `~/.profile` file for editing, add this line:

```
unset LC_CTYPE
```

and relogin.

Comment: Thanks, Gunnar. Strangely the message disappeared shortly after I reboot

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the message left after I reboot.

In any case, I also explicitly set the `LC_CTYPE` in the default locale

`sudo vim /etc/default/locale`

I typed the following

```
LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales`

which is a screen like this
[image]

For such screens, you have to use <kbd>tab</kbd> and <kbd>space</kbd> and your cursor keys to navigate

SElect the locale you want. In my case that will be `en_US.UTF-8`

[image]

If you do this correctly, 2 screens later you should see

[image]

Then apparently you need to `sudo reboot`