# Locale Problems Kubuntu 16.10

Tags: kubuntu, 16.10, locale

I have Kubuntu 16.10, Kernel Version: 4.8.0-42-generic

There is a problem with locales.

https://paste.ubuntu.com/24248684/

There ar missing some files or directory.

I have searched other posts (for examle: [How do I fix my locale issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162391/how-do-i-fix-my-locale-issue/229512#229512))

I tried to aplly

sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales "es_ES.UTF-8"

But i'm lost. My locale setting are Germany in regional and the detailed settings ar all in spanish.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please run the command `cat /etc/default/locale` and let us know what it outputs by editing your question.

Comment: xokuzo@xokuzo-ntb:~$ cat /etc/default/locale
#  File generated by update-locale
LANG=es_ES.UTF-8
xokuzo@xokuzo-ntb:~$

Comment: I installed de_DE.UTF-8 nd en_US.UTF-8 too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to generate the `nds_DE.UTF-8` locale:

```
sudo locale-gen nds_DE
```

*Edit:*

The problem proved to be that not all files belonging to the `locales` package were present, and reinstalling solved it:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall locales
```

Comment: https://paste.ubuntu.com/24248844/

Comment: @Xoktz: What does the command `dpkg-query -W locales` output?

Comment: xokuzo@xokuzo-ntb:~$ sudo dpkg-query -W locales
[sudo] password for xokuzo: 
locales 2.24-3ubuntu2

Comment: @Xoktz: Then run `sudo apt install --reinstall locales` and then try the generate command again.

Comment: https://paste.ubuntu.com/24248934/

Comment: @Xoktz: Ok, that solved your problem, didn't it?

Comment: yes it solved. https://paste.ubuntu.com/24248944/

Comment: @Xoktz: You're welcome. Can you please click the gray checkmark to the left of the answer to show others that the problem was solved.