# Winetricks showing options in different languages

Tags: wine, mint, winetricks

After installing winetricks, I noticed something odd. A lot of my options upon going into the specific choices such as "install a game" were in different languages except for "uninstall a game". My choices seem to be in random languages. This makes it very frustrating for me as I don't know what any of these options do. Does anyone have any idea as to what the issue might be?

Comment: I have never seen this before, but maybe there is a possibility that more than one language is set in the `/etc/locale.gen` file.  To see it run `cat /etc/locale.gen | grep -v \#`  I believe that you should only see something like `en_US.UTF-8 UTF-`.

Comment: It has en_US.UTF-8 and UTF-8. I've searched around and no one is having the same problem as me. Does the GTK warning in terminal saying "Locale not supported" the issue?

Comment: I think so, but I am not 100% sure.   I guess it wouldn't hurt to try setting the locale:  https://askubuntu.com/a/227513/231142

Comment: Instead of editing the question with the solution, please put the solution as an answer, then select that answer as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

*The OP seems to have solved this and posted the following as an edit to their question. I am reproducing it below so the question can be answered.*

---

> EDIT: I fixed it! I did so by completely uninstalling and reinstalling it! (Probably should have tried that first, derp)
>
> I have a picture attached below showing my issue:
>
> Example of what is happening:
>
> [image]